# Не срабатывает addEventListener по клику

Tags: javascript, click

Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый, но нигде не смог найти ответа. Пишу свою первую программу и не могу разобраться почему:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function hihi(){ alert('hihi'); });
```

срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку,

а вариант:

```
function hi() {alert('HI')};
btn.addEventListener("click", hi());
```

срабатывает сразу при загрузке страницы.

Comment: Уберите скобки после hi тут btn.addEventListener("click", hi());

Comment: большое спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `hi()` - это вызов фунции, а `addEventListener` ждёт ссылку на функцию - `btn.addEventListener("click", hi)`.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно как-нибудь в конструкции btn.addEventListener("click", hi) передать функции hi какой-нибудь аргумент?

Comment: Можно обернуть вызов с аргументами в анонимную функцию, можно использовать замыкание, можно передать данные через атрибут элемента DOM, наконец использовать [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Comment: Еще раз спасибо